# Merged calendar (schedule/roster/shift) view of the whole team

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-outlook, calendar, google-calendar

My colleagues and me are looking for a way to have a combined calendar of our work shifts, to be able to have a merged and printable calendar for example in a format like this:

desired output format
[image: desired output format]

Our monthly work schedules are available in both Outlook and Google calendars. Usually one event per day covering our whole shift, occasionally separated into two or three events on a given day. We need to be able to see specific person's work pattern, preferably the whole month in a single row.
At the moment our team is around 10 people, but this should be scalable to some extend.

I was thinking that we could share our Google Calendars, but there is no sensible display view available in web or phone app to see multiple calendars side by side. All the available views are more focused on the day, not the person.
If there was an easy option to export the calendar into excel, that would also be good.

Any advice?

Comment: It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. Have you had a chance to check the replies provided? Any update would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Outlook desktop client?

If so, we can see multiple calendars side by side as shown in the below figure by selecting the calendars you need.

[image]

In addition, we can also [export the calendar to a CSV file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-contacts-from-outlook-10f09abd-643c-4495-bb80-543714eca73f) via File>Open & Export>Import/Export.

Comment: Hmmm, if I don't find anything easier, this seems like a worthy solution, thanks!

Comment: Hi @Greg! If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I was just waiting to test it, but yes - not the easiest way I imagined but it works, thanks!